# How to connect database dynamically using zf3.?

Tags: zend-framework3

Here is the scenario, I have different database like document1, document2, document3 .... document100. These database are generating dynamically using same username and password.
So how I can connect this database dynamically using zf3.? I think it is not a good solution to give all connection string of all database in global.php, because these database are generating dynamically.

Please note that this should be work while running indexAction(), not before indexAction() function.

Please help me to find good solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you just need to change config for your database adapter. Did you try that?

Comment: ask more specific, provide sample database connection string like database engine you using. i think you can create instance of adapter by using your database information at indexAction and can use it to connect database